# QGIS installation on lubuntu (LXDE)

Tags: qgis

I'm unable to install QGIS on lubuntu (LXDE desktop). This is what it says on the terminal:

*Package qgis is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'qgis' has no installation candidate*

On previous attempt of installation the problem was in absence(?) of QT environment (if I understood correctly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im not sure about your distro, but on Ubuntu, you have to *edit /etc/apt/sources.list* file and add the qgis repository at the end (this is for 12.04 Precise):

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian precise main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian precise main
```

Then also add the public key through the terminal:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 997D3880
gpg --export --armor 997D3880 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then type

```
apt-get update
```

to refresh the packages list, and then you should be able to do: `apt-get install qgis`

Note: some of the commands may require root privileges (using sudo in front)

Comment: @Zoran It would be helpful if you would accept this as an answer by clicking on the checkmark.  I usually always upvote the answer first by clicking on the up arrow, then on the checkmark.